# Dynamic route not refetch data when click <Link

Tags: reactjs, next.js

NextJS 13.4.4

I have a page [id]: Dynamic route with fetch + cache: "no-store"
`const data = await getData(id)`

From list item page click an item to go to detail page. At the list page when hover to item to click, NextJS call 1 request fetch-server-response, I have console.log and server cmd terminal show data of item. I have action to change data of anything item, after click to go to detail page of item then UI still show old data before update of item and not refetch item, maybe it still use data when I hover to item in list page.

How to solve this problem?

Refetch new data to show

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.